# Exporting all blobs from sqlite to a files

Tags: linux, macos, bash, sqlite

Using this command:

```
sqlite3 my.db "SELECT writefile('object0.jpg', MyBlob) FROM MyTable WHERE id = 1"
```

I can save an image stored as blob in a table in my db.
How can I alter this so that all the images are saved instead of just 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a two-step, naive solution is an option, you could do:

```
sqlite3 my.db "SELECT id from MyTable" > /tmp/id.list
```

for getting the list of all ids, then

```
cat /tmp/id.list | while read id; do echo SELECT writefile\(\'object$id.jpg\', MyBlob\) FROM MyTable WHERE id = $id\;; done | sqlite3 my.db
```

for creating and executing commands for storing all the blobs.

Comment: It does not do anything. I tried with `head -n 1 /tmp/id.list > test.list` for 1 id and run the second command. I don't get an error but no file is produced

Comment: Ok, I figured the problem. How can I modify so that the $id is within quotes? I see that if I do "$id" or '$id' the value is not set

Comment: Is there way to do it in a single line?

Comment: @Jim: My sqlite kung-fu is too weak to do it in a signle line :(

Answer (score 7):

Use SQL string concatenation (`||`) to construct the file names:

```
sqlite3 my.db "SELECT writefile('object' || id || '.jpg', MyBlob) FROM MyTable"
```